# How to add drop shadow to any PNG in Android Compose?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, dropshadow, coil

I want do display images with an exact shadow using Compose (and Coil).

This is the desired shadow:

[image: image with drop shadow]

However, the shadow modifier only adds a shadow around the image bounds.

```
AsyncImage(
        modifier = Modifier.shadow(elevation = 4.dp),
        model = "http://my.image.url",
)
```

How can I achieve the shadow above using Compose?

Comment: Generally you add the shadow to the png.  The problem with adding it afterwards is that the app has no idea what in the image gets a dropshadow.  You can add it to the image node as a whole, but that wouldn't get the graphical look you want of the robot being shaded.  Adding it to the image programatically would require an AI algorithm to figure out what the image is and isn't.

Comment: @GabeSechan It doesn't need an AI. The old way was to use RenderScript, Alpha Channel Detection and Blur Filters. Thing is, RenderScript is deprecated, so I was hoping that there is a new way this can be done in Compose. It seems though, as there isn't.

Comment: There was no old way of doing this.  Renderscript was running computationally VERY expensive algorithms to do that.  It was never a recommended way of doing things, and required extremely high CPU /GPU usage.  The right way of doing this was always to just put the shadow into the base image.